# Flutter some package not found in pod

Tags: firebase, flutter, ads, google-ads-api

first of all, I want to add [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) in my pubspec.
after adding it the `pod install` command return 404 not found.

after it, I remove my podfile & podfile.lock and run `flutter clean` & `pod cache clean --all` and trying to run again and FirebaseAnalytic & GoogleSignIn return 404 not found too.

[image: GoogleSignIn]

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/4663

Comment: problem was solved,
it was because of the Google boycott in my country.